# how can I read cookies, that were set by domain A, from domain B via an inline javascript attached in domain B?

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to read cookies that were set by domain A (i know the name of the cookies), from domain B via an inline javascript code placed in domain B.

domain B inline javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://domainA.com/classifiead/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();

    </script>
```

http://domainA.com/classifiead/embed.js contains:

```
     $("#jsonpbtn2").click(function() {

   var url = 'http://domainA.com/classifiead/content2.php?callback=?'; 
  //  var id = info;
   $.getJSON(url, null, function(data) {
                 $('#textDiv').append(data.somecookie);
     });
});
```

http://domainA.com/classifiead/content2.php contains:

```
<?php 
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");
 header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

 $rtnjsonobj->id = 'test skdfbslkdj';
 $rtnjsonobj->somecookie =$_COOKIE['thisweb_last_75'];
echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';
```

?>

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have code executing server side on domain A. When your JavaScript code receive the cookie from domain A, then you can send the cookie to domain B.

If the cookie is a secure cookie or httponly, you can only read it via your server side script.

I suggest you to read this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cross-site_scripting_.E2.80.93_cookie_theft

Please pay attention: in your example you should create the object before assign properties. For example:

```
$rtnjsonobj = new stdClass();
$rtnjsonobj->id = 'test skdfbslkdj';
$rtnjsonobj->somecookie =$_COOKIE['thisweb_last_75'];
```

Comment: what about domain B, and if not, is there any way to do this?

Comment: In your example is not clear when the cookie is set from the domain A.

Comment: Cookie was set on domain A when the same user logged in on domain A

Comment: To do what, share a cookie between different domains?

Comment: Have you tried to create a `supercookie`? A "supercookie" is a cookie with a public suffix domain, like .com, .co.uk or k12.ca.us. On the other hand, if you need to exchange data in javascript from different domains you could try with `addEventListener` and `postMessage` methods.